# ¿Como puedo rotar un componente?

Tags: java, java-swing

Bueno resulta que tengo un JPanel(le puse de nombre barra), y quiero que se pueda poner verticalmente, he visto que hay un método de la clase Graphics2D que es rotate(), creo me podría servir para, aunque no entiendo como funciona, ni los datos que me pide, por eso he decidido consultar por aquí, por otra parte desconozco si los componentes que hay dentro de la barra también se rotan junto con la misma o que sucede con ellos, espero no tener que rotarlos por mi cuenta.

Esta es la barra:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Asi me gustaría que quede:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```java
package interfaz.barraFlotante;

import eventos.barraFlotante.BarraEventos;
import interfaz.principal.Asistente;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.RenderingHints;
import java.awt.Toolkit;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JCheckBox;
import javax.swing.JComboBox;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JSeparator;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.border.LineBorder;
import logica.MouseClicker;
import utilidades.Redimensionador;

public final class BarraFlotante extends JPanel {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private final Asistente PRUEBA = new Asistente();
    private final JLabel PLAY = PRUEBA.getPlay();
    private final JLabel DETENER = PRUEBA.getDetener();
    private final JLabel PAUSA = PRUEBA.getPausa();
    private final JLabel ATRAS = new JLabel(new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/atras.png")), JLabel.CENTER);
    private final JLabel ADELANTE = new JLabel(new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/adelante.png")), JLabel.CENTER);
    private final JLabel OCULTAR = new JLabel();
    private final JLabel CONTVLT = new JLabel();
    private final JTextField CONT = new JTextField();
    private final JLabel CONTPTS = new JLabel();
    private final JPanel PANELINFO2 = new JPanel();
    private final JPanel PANELINFO = new JPanel();
    private final JLabel RELOJ = new JLabel();
    private final JCheckBox TOGGLEPUNTOS = new JCheckBox();
    private final JPanel PANELPUNTOS = new JPanel();
    private final JComboBox<Object> PRESETS = new JComboBox<>();
    private final Color FONDO = new Color(210, 210, 210);

    public BarraFlotante() {

        setBounds((int) Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize().getSize().getWidth() / 2 - 220, 1, 511, 32);
        setLayout(null);
        setVisible(false);
        setOpaque(false);

        InitComponentes();
        InitEventos();

    }

    private void setOcultar() {

        OCULTAR.setBounds(getX() + 2, getHeight() - 1, 509, 15);
        OCULTAR.setHorizontalAlignment(0);
        MouseClicker.CONTENEDOR.add(OCULTAR);

    }

    private void setPaneles() {

        PANELINFO.setBounds(200, 3, 83, 26);
        PANELINFO.setOpaque(true);
        PANELINFO.setBackground(new Color(200, 200, 200));
        PANELINFO.setBorder(new LineBorder(Color.BLACK));
        PANELINFO.setLayout(null);
        add(PANELINFO);

        PANELINFO2.setBackground(new Color(200, 200, 200));
        PANELINFO2.setBounds(288, 3, 55, 26);
        PANELINFO2.setBorder(new LineBorder(Color.BLACK));
        PANELINFO2.setLayout(null);
        add(PANELINFO2);

        RELOJ.setBounds(348, 3, 50, 26);
        RELOJ.setBorder(new LineBorder(Color.BLACK));
        RELOJ.setOpaque(true);
        RELOJ.setBackground(new Color(200, 200, 200));
        RELOJ.setFont(new Font("Dialog", 1, 12));
        RELOJ.setText("00.00.00");
        add(RELOJ);

        PANELPUNTOS.setBounds(403, 3, 50, 26);
        PANELPUNTOS.setBackground(new Color(200, 200, 200));
        PANELPUNTOS.setVisible(true);
        PANELPUNTOS.setLayout(null);
        PANELPUNTOS.setBorder(new LineBorder(Color.BLACK));
        add(PANELPUNTOS);

    }

    private void setOpciones() {

        PLAY.setBounds(13, 0, 30, 30);
        PLAY.setText(null);
        add(PLAY);

        PAUSA.setBounds(44, 1, 30, 30);
        PAUSA.setText(null);
        add(PAUSA);

        DETENER.setBounds(72, 1, 30, 30);
        DETENER.setText(null);
        add(DETENER);

        ATRAS.setBounds(464, 1, 20, 30);
        ATRAS.setEnabled(false);
        ATRAS.setToolTipText("Ctrl+Z");
        add(ATRAS);

        ADELANTE.setBounds(488, 1, 20, 30);
        ADELANTE.setEnabled(false);
        ADELANTE.setToolTipText("Ctrl+Y");
        add(ADELANTE);

        PRESETS.setBounds(96, 4, 99, 23);
        PRESETS.setEditable(false);
        add(PRESETS);

        JLabel img = new JLabel(new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/ciclo.png")));
        img.setBounds(4, 6, 20, 16);
        PANELINFO.add(img);

        CONTVLT.setFont(new Font("Dialog", 1, 12));
        CONTVLT.setText("100 /");
        CONTVLT.setBounds(img.getWidth() + 7, 6, CONTVLT.getText().length() * 6, 15);
        PANELINFO.add(CONTVLT);

        CONT.setOpaque(false);
        CONT.setText("100");
        CONT.setEditable(true);
        CONT.setBounds(CONTVLT.getWidth() + 28, 8, 22, 10);
        CONT.setBorder(null);
        CONT.setFont(new Font("Dialog", 1, 12));
        PANELINFO.add(CONT);

        JLabel img1 = new JLabel(new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/contador.png")), JLabel.LEFT);
        img1.setBounds(1, 0, 30, 26);
        Redimensionador.iniciar(img1, 30, 26);
        PANELINFO2.add(img1);

        CONTPTS.setFont(new Font("Dialog", 1, 12));
        CONTPTS.setText("50");
        CONTPTS.setBounds(32, 4, 16, 20);
        PANELINFO2.add(CONTPTS);
        TOGGLEPUNTOS.setBounds(1, 5, 46, 17);
        TOGGLEPUNTOS.setOpaque(false);
        TOGGLEPUNTOS.setText("Ver");
        PANELPUNTOS.add(TOGGLEPUNTOS);

        JSeparator grabacion = new JSeparator();

        grabacion.setOrientation(1);
        grabacion.setVisible(true);
        grabacion.setBounds(90, 6, 30, 20);
        grabacion.setBackground(Color.BLUE);
        add(grabacion);

        JSeparator flechas = new JSeparator();

        flechas.setOrientation(1);
        flechas.setVisible(true);
        flechas.setBounds(457, 6, 30, 20);
        flechas.setBackground(Color.BLUE);
        add(flechas);

        repaint();

    }

    private void InitEventos() {

        BarraEventos eventos = new BarraEventos(this);

    }

    private void InitComponentes() {

        setPaneles();
        setOpciones();
        setOcultar();

    }

    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        int width = getWidth();
        int height = getHeight();
        Graphics2D graphics = (Graphics2D) g;
        graphics.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);

        //Draws the rounded opaque panel with borders.
        graphics.setColor(FONDO);
        graphics.fillRoundRect(0, 0, width - 1, height - 1, 29, 29);//paint background
        graphics.setColor(getForeground());
        graphics.drawRoundRect(0, 0, width - 1, height - 1, 29, 29);//paint border
//        graphics.rotate(180);

    }

    public final JLabel getPLAY() {
        return PLAY;
    }

    public final JLabel getDETENER() {
        return DETENER;
    }

    public final JLabel getPAUSA() {
        return PAUSA;
    }

    public final JLabel getATRAS() {
        return ATRAS;
    }

    public final JLabel getADELANTE() {
        return ADELANTE;
    }

    public final JLabel getOCULTAR() {
        return OCULTAR;
    }

    public final JLabel getCONTVLT() {
        return CONTVLT;
    }

    public final JTextField getCONT() {
        return CONT;
    }

    public final JLabel getCONTPTS() {
        return CONTPTS;
    }

    public final JPanel getPanelInfo2() {
        return PANELINFO2;
    }

    public final JPanel getPanelInfo() {
        return PANELINFO;
    }

    public final JLabel getReloj() {
        return RELOJ;
    }

    public final JCheckBox getTogglePuntos() {
        return TOGGLEPUNTOS;
    }

    public final JPanel getPanelPuntos() {
        return PANELPUNTOS;
    }

    public final JComboBox<Object> getPRESETS() {
        return PRESETS;
    }

    public final Color getFONDO() {
        return FONDO;
    }

}
`
```

Comment: tiene mucho que no uso graphics2d... pero ¿De casualidad intentaste ponerle el rotate al inicio del método?

Comment: si, probé tanto al inicio como al final, pero no me lo rotaba :(

Comment: y probaste usando transformaciones afines?

Comment: No, como funciona?

Comment: checa https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/geom/AffineTransform.html